# R rfacebook package - bad request

Tags: r, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to connect to Facebook to do some analysis, but am unable to connect. I had created the web app, have the appid and app secret code but when i try to execute the following command i get the error:

> fb_oauth <-
>   fbOAuth(app_id="xxx0",app_secret="xxx",extended_permissions =TRUE)

```
Error in init_oauth2.0(self$endpoint, self$app, scope = self$params$scope,  : 
  Bad Request (HTTP 400).
```

I have also added the site url in app settings: http://localhost:1410
[image: This is the facebook page settings]
I also get the the below error when fb page loads.
[image: Error when fb page loads]

but i do get the completion message on Facebook:

> Authentication complete. Please close this page and return to R.

Can anyone advise if am doing anything wrong or i have missed something?

Comment: And did you fill out all the field the error message mentions …?

Comment: Yes i added the ip address.

Comment: IP addresses don’t work well here I think. It’s better to use a domain name – can be a fake one like `mytestapp.local`, if you put that into your hosts file, so that your browser can resolve it. Also, addresses including non-standard ports can be problematic as well – I’d recommend setting the test system up so that it uses the default ports 80/443.